# Launch native IOS camera on a webApp

Tags: ios, iphone, html, mobile-safari

My webApp needs to scan a `QR code` so Im trying to launch the native IOS camera to read it.

I'm able to launch the camera with some `HTML` media captures like :

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
<input type="file">
```

but the camera doesn't scan the `QR code`.

Im testing with safari and there is no problem with `QR code` (if I open the camera and try to read the `QR code` it works perfectly.